# How to release @PreDestroy resources in Spring + Camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

In my application, running in **apache-tomcat** with **Spring** and **Camel**, I've a Class with a method annotated with `@PreDestroy`. The method **is** called when tomcat is shutdown, but I've problem: the PreDestroy method uses one of the Camel routes to release the class's resources, and the route is closed (I get the message "`WARN DirectProducer:54 - No consumers available on endpoint XYZ`")

Am I forgetting to do something else?
How can I release the resources?